# Show that $M \models (\exists x) (\alpha) $ if and only if there is an element $a\in A$ such that $M\models \alpha [s[x|a]]$.

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

Let $M$ be an $L$-structure for some language first order language $L$. Let $(\exists x)(\alpha)$ be an abbreviation for the formula $¬[(\forall x )(¬\alpha)]$.

Show that $M \models (\exists x) (\alpha) $ if and only if there is an element $a\in A$ such that $M\models \alpha [s[x|a]]$.

My attempt :

$M\models (\exists x)(\alpha)[s] \ \leftrightarrow \  M \models ¬(\forall x)(¬\alpha)[s] \ \leftrightarrow  \ \text{for each $a\in$ A}\ , M \not\ \not\models (¬\alpha)[s[x|a]] \leftrightarrow \text{there is no $a\in A$ s.t.} \  M\models (¬\alpha)[s[x|a]] \leftrightarrow \text{there is no $a\in A$ s.t.}\  M\not\models \alpha [s[x|a]] $

Now , I don't know where to go to show the required! any help please ?

> This is exercise $7$ section $1.7$ page $39$ from ***friendly introduction to logic*** by ***Leary***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Your attempt is almost right. By De Morgan's law (in metalanguage) you can prove
$$\text{there is no } a\in A \text{ s.t. }M\nvDash \alpha [s[x|a]]\iff \text{there is }a\in A \text{ s.t. } M\vDash \alpha[s[x|a]].$$</strike>

---

Oh, I make a mistake. Formalize the proof of given statement then
$$
\begin{aligned}
M\models (\exists x)(\alpha)[s]  &\iff & M\models \lnot(\forall x)\lnot(\alpha)[s] &\qquad(1)\\
& \iff &\text{not}(M\models (\forall x)\lnot(\alpha)[s]) &\qquad(2)\\
& \iff  &\text{not}(\text{for all }a\in A,\>\> M\models \lnot(\alpha)[s[x|a]]) &\qquad(3)\\
\end{aligned}
$$

Can you find what step in your 'proof' makes the trouble?

Comment: Could you clarify it more ? How to use De Morgan's law to prove this ? ( which law ?! )

Comment: @Element Exactly, we use the De Morgan's Laws for Quantifiers
$$\lnot\forall x \lnot \phi \iff \exists x \phi.$$
(In metalanguage) take $\phi=(M\vDash \alpha[s[x|a]])$ then you get desired result.

Comment: Ok but , I don't see why ( there is no $a\in A$ s.t. $M\not\models \alpha[s[x|a]] \equiv$ there is $a\in$ s.t. $M\models \alpha[s[x|a]]$ in metalanguage ! I even think this is not true.

Comment: @Element Your metalanguage is also classical logic. Take $\phi(a)=(M\models \alpha[s[x|a]])$ and formalize this sentence you get
$$\text{there is no $a\in A$ s.t. }\phi(a) \iff \lnot \forall a \lnot\phi(a)$$

Comment: I think this is untrue as , $$ \text{there is no } a\in A \text{ s.t } \phi(a) \leftrightarrow \forall a ¬\phi (a)$$.

Comment: @Element Oh, oh... Sorry for my mistake. I modify my answer.

Comment: Yes , I see where the step which created the problem. but I can't see why this step is wrong!. in my text , it's said that , $$M\models ¬(\alpha) \text{ iff } M\not\models \alpha$$ so I followed this definition in step 2 ( which made the problem! ) , I mean , Why did you make "not" out of the statement not in it?

Comment: @Element Check the between second and third step in your 'proof'. Your argue that
$$M\models \lnot\forall x\lnot \alpha[s] \iff \text{for all }x\in A,\, \text{not }M\models \lnot\alpha[s[x|\alpha]]. $$

Comment: Yeah , I did! thank you very much for your help and for your time :) by the way , what code do you use to type this left-right arrow ? I use the code \$\leftrightarrow\$ but the arrow i get is the one in my question not like the one you used in comments! ( the difference is the mine has one line between the heads of the arrow , but yours is width )

Comment: @Element I use the code `\iff` to type the left-right arrow.

Comment: Oh , thanx again.